# Does BinaryReader read all data types in little-endian format?

Tags: c#, .net, endianness, binaryreader

For [`BinaryReader.ReadInt32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readint32(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) and [`BinaryReader.ReadSingle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readsingle(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) the documentation of .Net says:

> BinaryReader reads this data type in little-endian format.

**So I reason that the BinaryReader will read this data types in little-endian format even if my computer architecture (verified by [`BitConverter.isLittleEndian`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian(v=vs.110).aspx)) were based on big-endian format.**

But for [`BinaryReader.ReadChars()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readchars(v=vs.110).aspx) (returning Char[]) and [`BinaryReader.PeekChar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.peekchar(v=vs.110).aspx) (returning Int32) there are no remarks about the byte order.

Now I'm not sure if these methods interpreting bytes depending on the computer architecture or if they are little-endian based, too. Especially I am confused about `BinaryReader.PeekChar()` that returns the same data type like `BinaryReader.ReadInt32()`. So it would make sense that this method also reads bytes in little-endian format.

Imagine this situation: My application is running on a big-endian based computer architecture and tries to read a big-endian based binary file. In this case I would have to reverse the byte order for `BinaryReader.ReadInt32()` and `BinaryReader.ReadSingle()` (see code below). But do I have to do the same thing for `BinaryReader.PeekChar()` and `BinaryReader.ReadChars()`? Unfortunately I don't have a computer / operatingsystem which is based on big-endian. But my application should be compatible to this architecture.

```
public class ReverseBinaryReader: BinaryReader
{
    public ReverseBinaryReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) : base(stream, encoding) { }

    public override int ReadInt32()
    {
        var data = base.ReadBytes(4);
        Array.Reverse(data);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
    }

    public override float ReadSingle()
    {
        var data = base.ReadBytes(4);
        Array.Reverse(data);
        return BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the char-centric methods, endianness is defined and handled entirely by the `Encoding` that is being used, which is a parameter when constructing the reader.

Comment: The source code for the CLI is available to you can look into the implementation there to get your answer. 
 https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binaryreader.cs,4f6cad84482876ff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are character-based APIs, their interpretation depends on the *encoding* being used. And since both [Little-endian and Big-endian UTF16 encodings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) are supported, there's no single answer to your question.

(And note, it's *necessary* for you to clearly know what encoding was used to create the binary data in the first place if you want to be able to read it successfully anyway)

Comment: Thank you so far! This answers my question related to `BinaryReader.ReadChars()` but not for `BinaryReader.PeekChar()`.

Comment: No, it's still the same for `PeekChar`. The interpretation of the character value depends on the encoding. Note that what is returned by `PeekChar` is effectively a `Char` value (which is always a UTF16 code point, but may have been decoded from another encoding). The return type is `int` to allow the `-1` out of range value to be used. (One of those "why did they choose for this API to use return values to signal problems versus all of the other APIs back in 1.1 which threw exceptions, even if as here failure was expected?" methods)

Comment: Ahhh. Now I got it :) Thanks!